# ASP.NET Forms Authentication always redirecting back to Login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, forms-authentication, .net-4.5

I have a problem with an incredibly simple website using simple Forms authentication.
I have a a single page Default.aspx and a Login.aspx.

Default.aspx is protected by `<deny users="?" />`

The Login.aspx calls

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage( tbUserName.Text, chPersist.Checked );
```

I used Fiddler to check if the redirect works. It does. But the Default page always redirects back to the Login page (HTTP/1.1 302 Found).
**The cookie is created as expected and Fiddler tells me it's there. But it just won't load the default page.**

I tried so many combinations, but the only thing that makes the default page load "successfully" is when I turn **off** the deny="?" rule in IIS/web.config. But then all users can get to the page, which is not what I want.

Web.config on the server and my machine:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

**Ironically all this is working great in any case when I debug the site in Visual Studio, but upon deployment it does not work. The web.config is deployed with the site.**

I have no idea why this still isn't working.
Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Try recycle the application pool.. and then restart the IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

This can be as one solution for you. 
If you have the following line of code in your web.config file remove it.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could check, that IIS has activated Forms Authentication for that site. If this is disabeld, it might result in odd behaviour when trying to authenticate via form.